# Enable gzip compression on webpack-dev-server?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

How do you enable gzip compression on the webpack-dev-server?  It doesn't appear to be on by default.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1) Insert this line before `app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')...`:

```
app.use(express.compress());
```

2) According to [source code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/lib/Server.js#L114) there is undocumented option `compress`:

```
$ webpack-dev-server ... --compress
```

Comment: I'm using the client and not the API, is there a option I can pass?

Comment: Thanks, that worked - `devServer: { compress: true }`

Comment: Is there a way to enable compressing for images etc? the `compress` option seems to compress js but not pngs for example

Comment: @dougajmcdonald PNG and JPEG are compressed file formats, so you cannot compress them more (attempting to do so would not significantly change the file size)

Comment: @KevinBorders I was talking more that the compression loader doesn't even touch image files. You definitely can compress compressed images and the file size change would entirely depend on the input and output compression settings.

Comment: This no longer works, as utility middleware are no longer bundled with Express.

Answer (score 2):

If you can find `app.use(devMiddleware)` in your project, replace it with:

```
var compression = require('compression');
app.use(compression({}));
app.use(devMiddleware);
```

And `npm install -D compression`

Answer (score 1):

To configure it in your web pack config, use the `compression` module.

`"devServer": {
        compress: true,
        before(app) {
            app.use(compression({}));
        },
    },`