# Make webpack 4 serve .css.gz files in index.html

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using webpack version 4 for generating builds in my react project. CompressionPlugin is generating the chunk files with `.css.gz`, `.css` and `.css.map` extension.

Usually, the chunk with `.css` extension is served in the build `index.html` file. I need to know how to serve `.css.gz` files instead of `.css` files in the `index.html`?

Comment: Transfer compression is handled by the web server on the edge of your request-response cycle. In production, this usually means a reverse proxy or a static file server such as nginx or apache. These servers compress and cache files in memory leading to better performance than by doing it by hand. I'm not sure what sort of use case could lead you to this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The easier fix would be to use a nodejs server.
`app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')...`

or take a look at 
[Enable gzip compression on webpack-dev-server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785313/enable-gzip-compression-on-webpack-dev-server)
https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/two-quick-ways-to-reduce-react-apps-size-in-production-82226605771a

[using gzip compression with webpack and express, still serving bundle.js instead of bundle.js.gz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50603021/using-gzip-compression-with-webpack-and-express-still-serving-bundle-js-instead)

[Serve static gzip files using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967270/serve-static-gzip-files-using-node-js)

Comment: Thanks, @subhendu.I have tried using the dev middleware but it's not working in my case. Is there any other way to do this without using the middleware?